# Error al encontrar una columna en una base de datos

Tags: java, sql

tengo un error al guardar los datos de mi proyecto en una SQL
Esto es el código para guardar:

```
}else if(tabla==2){
            String url="INSERT INTO registroboleta (NombresCompletos,Cantidad,Paradero,HoraSalida,Ciudad,Codigo,CVV,Costo,Date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            SQL sql=new SQL();
            Connection cn=sql.dataBase();
            PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement(url);
            ps.setString(1,cliente );
            ps.setInt(2, cantidad);
            ps.setString(3, paradero);
            ps.setString(4,hS);
            ps.setString(5, ciudad);
            ps.setString(6,codigo);
            ps.setString(7, CVV);
            ps.setString(8, costo);
            ps.setString(9, date);
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Reserva almacenada con éxito!", "Éxito", 0, new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/net/software/src/image/exito32x32.png")));
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Hubo un error inesperado, no se pudo guardar los datos, contacte con el creador del programa.", "Error", 0, new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/net/software/src/image/error32x32.png")));
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Exactamente el error me marca en la línea 56, de la cual es el

> int i=ps.executeUpdate();

Ahora, el código para obtener los datos para insertarlos en la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
String nomUser=jlNombresUsuario.getText();
        String paradero=jcbParadero.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String horaSalida=jcbHoraSalida.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String ciudad=jtxtCiudad.getText();
        String codigo=jtxtCodigo.getText();
        String cvv=jtxtCVV.getText();
        double costo=2.50*Integer.parseInt(jtxtCantidad.getText());
        int cant=Integer.parseInt(jtxtCantidad.getText());
        String cost=String.valueOf(costo);
        SaveInformation.getInstance().saveInformationMYSQL(null, 2, nomUser,cant,paradero,horaSalida, ciudad, codigo,cvv,cost,Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
```

Y las columnas puestas en la base de datos es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Costo' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
at net.software.src.utils.SaveInformation.saveInformationMYSQL(SaveInformation.java:56)
at net.software.src.jframes.Compra.jbtComprarActionPerformed(Compra.java:144)
```

Ayuda :c
De ante mano, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cuando lees los valores para después insertarlos, declaras una variable con el nombre `cost` y luego al asignarla en el insert le llamas `costo` (como el nombre del campo.

Deberias arreglar uno u otro sitio, por ejemplo, en el código para insertar:

```
...

ps.setString(8, cost);
...
```

Comment: Ya lo intenté, también cambie el tipo de dato que ingresará en el campo "Costo", pero me sale el mismo error